# How does threading work in Mule 1.3?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, mule

I have a tcp endpoint which send messages to a java component that calls a stored procedure in db and do some processing on the result and return it to the same tcp.
What I knew that every tcp request will be in it's own thread , but if the messages comes from the same connection does that mean i'll have only one thread , I need to configure mule to make the java component multi-threaded.
The only thing I found is this :
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Tuning+Performance#TuningPerformance-pooling
and I can't understand it :D

Comment: ok I'm trying pooled-component but i'm not sure this will make a new thread for each new message to the java component

Answer (score 1):

In Mule 3, whose doc you've linked in your question, message receivers (ie inbound endpoints) typically have a dedicated work manager with a pool of threads assigned to process requests in parallel (the exception is the JMS connector which acts a little different).

So in your case, the TCP inbound endpoint will have, by default, 16 threads assigned to deal with incoming requests that hits the single open TCP socket.

No need to use pooled components.

EDIT: The question is about Mule 1.3, which is super old and has a very different threading model. In that case, each endpoint has a different thread pool.

Comment: Can you clearify the relation between workmanager , message receivers and connectors please ? For instance if I have 1 connector, and 2 different message receivers related to this connector how many work manager will I have ?

Comment: One connector has 3 work managers: one for receivers, one for dispatchers and one for requesters. If you have one connector with 2 endpoints, the 2 endpoints will share the same work manager, ie same thread pool.

Comment: I was also expecting that however, i have two different endpoints for same connector and the receivers for this endpoints have different work managers. may be this is related to my configuration but how can i change it. By the way i am talking about Mule 1.3 version.

Comment: Mule 1.3 is 7 years old, you probably meant 3.3.1? I don't see how two inbound endpoints can have different work managers: `AbstractMessageReceiver.getWorkManager()` calls `connector.getReceiverWorkManager()`, ie they share the same work manager as provided by their common connector.

Comment: I really meant 1.3, in my company there is this old version. When i look at code i see AbstractMessageReceiver constructor there is this code. workManager = this.connector.createReceiverWorkManager(endpoint.getName()); I guess this is different in old version. Messagereceivers at different endpoints have same threadprofile  coming from connector but different thread pools.